# Path Variables and ThymeLeaf no CSS

Tags: html, css, spring, thymeleaf

So I have the following controller that maps to the same ThymeLeaf template:

```
@GetMapping(value="/nextStep/{id}")
public String nextStep(@PathVariable int id) {
    return "nextStep";
}


@GetMapping(value="/xxx")
public String nextStep() {
    return "nextStep";
}
```

If I navigate to `/xxx`, the page has my css applied.  If I navigate to `/nextStep/10` the template displays but there is no css applied.

The template is simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    </head>
    <body>
Hello world<br>
    </body>
</html>
```

There are no exceptions thrown in this example.

Comment: Maybe is because of relative pathing? i.e. your css path is `https://www.example.com/my.css`. In your `/xxx` using `my.css` you access  `https://www.example.com/my.css`. In your `/nextStep/{id}` using `my.css` you access `https://www.example.com/nextStep/my.css`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need put CSS path like this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/my.css}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think i have the same problem, all pages load with css all right. but if i access localhost:8080/group/3 the page will come without css (even the pages was in the same directory).

```
@GetMapping(value = "/group/{id}")
```

I found a shortcut to avoid this issue:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/group-{id}")
```

In my case this works fine, i hope work on your too.

Comment: This is a better solution. Thanks @Mathias